# Matrix represents weighted graph

Tags: graphs

In a question I've been given a 5x5 matrix that I'm told represents a weighted graph, and no other information. Here is an example:

0 4 5 2 2
3 0 3 3 1
1 3 0 5 2
2 4 4 0 2
2 3 2 5 0

My question is, how does this represent a weighted graph? I think that each number at position [i,j] in the matrix represents the length between the nodes i and j in the graph, am I correct? Is this the most likely representation or are there other ways that I am not aware of?

Comment: Indeed, this is the only reasonable convention.

Comment: Just being picky, but that's likely a representation of an edge-weighted *digraph*, since the matrix isn't symmetric.